Player not rotating in the direction hes moving Godot4.2.2
So im pretty new to godot and im trying to let my player rotate smoothly in the direction hes moving to.
Right now he just clips between the 8 possible moving directions, so im basicly trying to have a smooth transition between those directions. I tried a couple different things but none of them worked, most of the time the character just rotates permanently or in random directions
extends CharacterBody3D

const NormalSpeed := 180
const SprintSpeed := 360
const SneakSpeed := 90

const fall_acce := 60

const jump_impulse := 1000

var target_velocity := Vector3.ZERO

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

func _physics_process(delta):
    
    #Stores the input direction
    var direction := Vector3.ZERO
    
    #just checking for input and BASIC moving based on that
    if Input.is_action_pressed("m_forward"):
        direction.x += 1
    if Input.is_action_pressed("m_backward"):
        direction.x -= 1
    if Input.is_action_pressed("m_left"):
        direction.z -= 1
    if Input.is_action_pressed("m_right"):
        direction.z += 1
        
    #Normalizing
    if direction != Vector3.ZERO:
        direction = direction.normalized()
        $Pivot.basis = Basis.looking_at(direction)
        
    
    
    if not is_on_floor(): 
        target_velocity.y = target_velocity.y - (fall_acce * delta)
        
    #Extra Movement
    #Sprint
    var speed: int
    if Input.is_action_pressed("m_sprint"):
        speed = SprintSpeed
    else:
        speed = NormalSpeed
        
    #Sneak
    if Input.is_action_pressed("sneak"):
        get_node("CollisionShape3D").disabled = true 
        speed = SneakSpeed
    else:
        get_node("CollisionShape3D").disabled = false 
        
    #Jump
    if is_on_floor() and Input.is_action_just_pressed("jump"):
        target_velocity.y = jump_impulse * delta
        
    
        
    
    target_velocity.x = direction.x * speed * delta
    target_velocity.z = direction.z * speed * delta
        
    
    
    velocity = target_velocity
    move_and_slide()


Fixed id was just kinda stupid^^
if direction != Vector2.ZERO:   direction = direction.normalized()   $Pivot.rotation.y = lerp_angle($Pivot.rotation.y, atan2(-direction.x, -direction.y), delta * angular_acce)

You can answer your own question. That way the code formatting would be preserved.
